# Retrieve CDC net changes without primary key but with unique field

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the net changes similar to `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>(from_lsn , to_lsn, 'all with mask')` of tables that don't have a primary key but do have a constraint that ensures that one (or more) column(s) is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I think I have a solution that works, let me know if there's a better solution or if you see a bug in mine.

Let's assume a capture instance named `capture_instance` of a table with unique column `ID` and non-unique columns `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and variables `@from_lsn` and `@to_lsn`.

```
WITH
cdc_all AS (
  -- Retrieve the change table with all changes
  SELECT *
  FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_instance(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all')
),
f AS (
  SELECT cdc_all.*, ops.[delete], ops.[insert], ops.[update], ops.[net_op]
  FROM cdc_all
  INNER JOIN (
    -- Retrieve three flags for insert, update and delete and the net operation
    -- also filter insert + delete pairs because it results in no change
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT ID
           , MAX(CASE WHEN __$operation = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [delete]
           , MAX(CASE WHEN __$operation = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [insert]
           , MAX(CASE WHEN __$operation = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [update]
           , MIN(__$operation) [net_op]
      FROM cdc_all
      GROUP BY ID
    ) ops
    WHERE NOT (ops.[delete] = 1 AND ops.[insert] = 1)
  ) ops ON cdc_all.ID = ops.ID
)
SELECT net.[max_lsn], f.[net_op] __$operation
     , (CASE WHEN net.__$update_mask != 0x0 THEN net.__$update_mask ELSE NULL END) __$update_mask
     , f.[ID], [field1], [field2], [field3]
FROM f
INNER JOIN (
  -- bitwise OR the __$update_mask of the updates
  -- also retrieve the last lsn of each row which should be used as the __$start_lsn of the result set
  SELECT ID
       , CAST(SUM(DISTINCT CAST((CASE WHEN f.[__$operation] = 4 AND f.[insert] != 1 THEN f.[__$update_mask] ELSE 0 END) as int)) as varbinary(2)) [__$update_mask]
       , MAX(__$start_lsn) [max_lsn]
  FROM f
  GROUP BY ID
) net ON f.ID = net.ID AND f.__$start_lsn = net.[max_lsn]
```

To match the behavior of `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_` exactly the size of the varbinary at the end should be as small as possible for all fields to fit, but a larger value wouldn't break the functionality.